# solve an argmax problem of two unknowns given covariance matrices

Tags: variance, multivariate-analysis, optimization, covariance, high-dimensional

The problem is:
For a pair of random variable $(X,Y)$, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^p$, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^q$, write $\Sigma_{XX}=var(X)$, $\Sigma_{YY}=var(Y)$, $\Sigma_{YX}=cov(Y,X)$.

Define
$(\alpha^*, \beta^*)=$ argmax  $\alpha^T\Sigma_{YX}\beta$ s.t. $\alpha^T\Sigma_{YY}\alpha=1$, $\beta^T\Sigma_{XX}\beta=1$.

Assume that $\Sigma_{YY}>0$, $\Sigma_{XX}>0$. How can I solve for $(\alpha^*, \beta^*)$ if $\Sigma_{YY}$, $\Sigma_{XX}$, $\Sigma_{YX}$ are known?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag (you'll have to remove an existing tag) & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the maximum singular value of a matrix $A$ is the maximizer
of
$$
\sigma_{\max}=\max_{x,y}x^{T}Ay
$$

over the set $\left\Vert x\right\Vert =\left\Vert y\right\Vert =1$.
The constraint sets your care about are a little different though,
as they are ellipsoids rather than spheres.

The way to solve the problem you state is to apply a change of variables,
changing $a\rightarrow x\Sigma_{XX}^{-1/2}$, and similarly for $b\rightarrow\Sigma_{YY}^{-1/2}y$
(we use the (principal) matrix square root here, which is well defined
for positive definite covariance matrices). You then get a singular
value problem of the above form which can be solved in terms of $x$
and $y$, and the solution mapped back to $a$ and $b$ vectors.